# Objective-C, Authorization fails to perform function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication

I'm trying to create an Authorization to copy a file using SMJobBless, although I can't get it to work. The helper app is successfully authorized and the `Job is available!` message appears before the `[self copyFile]` method, but the copyFile always fails. If someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong or provide and example of how to make this work that would be great.

appDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SMJobBlessAppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *_textField;
}

- (BOOL)blessHelperWithLabel:(NSString *)label error:(NSError **)error;
- (void)copyFile;

@end
```

appDelegate.m

```
#import <ServiceManagement/ServiceManagement.h>
#import <Security/Authorization.h>
#import "appDelegate.h"

@implementation SMJobBlessAppController
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self blessHelperWithLabel:@"com.apple.bsd.SMJobBlessHelper" error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong!");
    } else {
        /* At this point, the job is available. However, this is a very
         * simple sample, and there is no IPC infrastructure set up to
         * make it launch-on-demand. You would normally achieve this by
         * using a Sockets or MachServices dictionary in your launchd.plist.
         */
        NSLog(@"Job is available!");

        [self->_textField setHidden:false];

        [self copyFile];

    }
}

- (void)copyFile {

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *sourceFile = @"~/path/to/file.txt";
    NSString *destFile = @"~/Library/Application Support/myApp/file.txt";

    if ([fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourceFile toPath:destFile error:&error] == YES) {
        NSLog (@"[FILE] Copied.");
        // NSLog (@"Copy successful");
    } else {
        NSLog (@"[FILE] Copy failed.");
        NSLog (@" %@ %@",sourceFile, destFile);
        // NSLog (@"Copy failed");
    }

    [fileManager release];

    return;
}

- (BOOL)blessHelperWithLabel:(NSString *)label error:(NSError **)error;
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    AuthorizationItem authItem      = { kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper, 0, NULL, 0 };
    AuthorizationRights authRights  = { 1, &authItem };
    AuthorizationFlags flags        =   kAuthorizationFlagDefaults              | 
                                        kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed    |
                                        kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize          |
                                        kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

    AuthorizationRef authRef = NULL;

    /* Obtain the right to install privileged helper tools (kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper). */
    OSStatus status = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, &authRef);
    if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create AuthorizationRef, return code %i", status);
    } else {
        /* This does all the work of verifying the helper tool against the application
         * and vice-versa. Once verification has passed, the embedded launchd.plist
         * is extracted and placed in /Library/LaunchDaemons and then loaded. The
         * executable is placed in /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools.
         */
        result = SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (CFStringRef)label, authRef, (CFErrorRef *)error);
    }

    return result;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're totally missing the point of `SMJobBless`. It doesn't magically make your current app able to do privileged things.  Instead, it installs and runs a separate helper tool, which is allowed to do privileged things, but should do nothing else (as little as possible).

You need to move your code in `copyFile` to [the `main` function in `SMJobBlessHelper.c`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/SMJobBlessHelper_SMJobBlessHelper_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010071-SMJobBlessHelper_SMJobBlessHelper_c-DontLinkElementID_7).  (And since that's a C file, you'll have to either rewrite it in C -- perhaps using CoreFoundation -- or you'll have to change the tool to use Objective-C.  Nobody said this would be easy.)

Comment: I think it's more a case of not exactly knowing how or why it's so difficult. I haven't found an answer anywhere that gives the slightest clue of how to copy files with elevated privileges. I've created plenty of (.pkg) installer packages that obviously need authorization, and it's incredibly easy — why should this be any different?

Comment: How do you think the installer system actually copies the files? It isn't magic -- there is code inside of it that does something much like what you're trying to do. It's not a fundamentally simple operation, it's just that you're used to working with a system that did all the work for you.

Comment: I posted the question so maybe someone could help me figure out how it is done, or at least guide me to something useful. Apparently you're more into judging me than actually helping.

Comment: Sorry to sound judgmental -- just wondering how you found the SMJobBless sample code w/o reading the [read me](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) and [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/ServiceManagementFwRef/ServiceManagement_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SMJobBless). Seriously, the thing to do is to move your code into the helper tool. If your question is specifically "how do I copy a file to a location that requires special privileges", you could have asked that, yes?

Comment: As for "why is this so hard?" -- see Apple's docs: [Code Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/SecuritySvcs/SecuritySvcs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002650-SW1) and [Elevating Privileges Safely](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW1) to start. If you're going to be running your code with privileges, on end-users' systems, I hope you've at least read the background material.